# Как правильно делать кеширование запросов ajax

Tags: php, ajax, кэширование

В идеале мне нужно кешировать ajax запросы и если произошли изменения то проверять и обновлять кеш.
   Вот пример на js и php, как мне понять кешируются запросы или нет?

```
// js
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/search_objects/',
    data: {
        search_category: categories, // показать первые 12 результатов
        query: _this.val() // поисковая фраза
    },
    cache:true,
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {

       },
    error: function () {
     } 
 })

// php 

   header("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

   header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600, must-revalidate");
   header('Pragma:cache');

   print json_encode($suggestions);

/// в ответ приходит заголовок 

 Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600, must-revalidate
 Connection:close
 Content-Encoding:gzip
 Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
 Date:Thu, 19 Nov 2015 18:41:15 GMT
 Pragma:cache
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что если Вы хотите использовать кеширование, Вы обязаны использовать GET (а не POST) запросы.

Answer (score 1):

[jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> **ifModified** (default: false)
>   Type: Boolean
>   Allow the request to be successful only if the response has changed since the last request. This is done by checking the Last-Modified header. Default value is false, ignoring the header. In jQuery 1.4 this technique also checks the 'etag' specified by the server to catch unmodified data.
>
> **cache** (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>   Type: Boolean
>   If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

Можно еще использовать прокси (nginx или apache mod_proxy) и тогда кэшированные ответы ловить по 301-коду